# Display data using foreign key

Tags: yii, foreign-keys

I'm using yii1. I have two tables: trekalbum and trekgallery. album_id is foreign key in trekgallery table. I want to display the data of both table ie trekalbum and trekgallery in view. I am only able to display data of trekgallery. So, how could I display data of trekalbum using foreign key? 
thanks in advance[image]

Comment: Please show some code of yours. Otherwise we can barely help you.

Comment: Also your tags should tell something about the technology you use.

Comment: Also it ill be a lot easier if you show your tables as actual tables with columns and rows

Comment: Also it'll be a lot more useful if you just do your own homework.

Comment: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.arr